# Layman's explanation of the mysterious occurrence of quantum tunneling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

I see much talk about probability and functions, quantum states and ball-in-a-pit analogies.

Bah.

**I would like an easy summary about the principles behind, demonstrations of, and application from the effect of quantum tunneling suitable for a high-school freshkid.**

Being  a curious person, this seems very interesting. I appear to be more used to the classical approach, where a ball either goes in or goes out, and doesn't shove a tiny shaving of itself out of the pit like in quantum tunneling. That is why I need an explanation.

According to [this interesting Wikipedia article,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28temperature%29) 1 attoKelvin is the temperature required for 'macroscopic teleportation of objects.' Intuition in my mind tells me it is because the wavelength of an object increases as it gets colder, but I can't connect the dots smoothly. *Help please?*

Comment: It's very hard to correct misconceptions like yours, which is why we try to teach high school kids how to do it right from the start. That, of course, involves the ability to not see the world as a collection of balls. Let us know when you are ready for a higher level of abstraction than "marbles, marbles everywhere". Tunneling of light can be demonstrated quite easily with a few pieces of good glass, but the analysis involves math... which you seem to despise, so that's no help.

Comment: Classical approaches just don't work in the quantum world. Probabilities, functions, and quantum states do. I'm sorry, but you have to dive in, hold your breath, and struggle for a while before you break surface again and look at the world differently. Ignore your intuition - it is great for throwing baseballs, but no good at all for tunneling photons, electrons, and protons (oh my!).

Comment: It is not clear the question, but I don't agree with @CuriousOne's comment, and I think your question is valid. A classical view in terms of "balls" is always at hand because we experience world that way. We don't so experience the quantum world. To explain it we use Quantum Mechanics which provides great accuracy so far. Still, it does not provide a clear picture of what particles can be imagined to be like, while being very accurate in stating outcomes of experiments. So up to now we can obtain tunneling as a solution to Schrodinger's equation, but not rule out different interpretations.

Comment: @rmhleo: You don't experience the world that way, either, you just don't know where to look for macroscopic quantum phenomena until you are being told about them. Matter and electromagnetism are all macroscopic manifestations of the quantum world and "hard balls" wouldn't even exist without it. The problem arises when someone insists that their immediate "experience" has some deeper meaning for nature. It doesn't. What you "experience" is selected for you by evolution, it's not part of the rules by which the world runs.

Comment: For a high school kid, you might try "Minute Physics" on youtube.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTodS8hkSDg though they don't go into detail on this subject but some of their videos are quite good.   I also love the particle adventure for no-math summaries:  http://www.particleadventure.org/

Comment: @userLTK yeah, but on minute physics  he really puts his foot to the floor in the explanation, and he still winds up 30 secs over time, saw it first time last night

Comment: "Minute physics" has it almost right, but then they ruined it all by saying "... see, the quantum world is probabilistic...". That's simply not true. The core of quantum physics is superposition of states, which does not exist in probability theory. The core of probability theory, on the other hand, are the central limit theorems, which also don't exist in quantum mechanics. None of us would be here if they did... we would all be part of one giant gaussian blob. No cigar.

Comment: I agree with everyone above that you need to learn these thing in a systematic way. You are asking us to pour 10L water into a 1L cup. The cup being your mind. Make the cup bigger and then you might understand it clearly. 

Having said that, a very good demonstration that is almost mathematically equivalent to 1D tunneling is the formation of evanescent waves when light undergoes total internal reflection. Probably you could check it out as wave nature of light might be something that is less mind boggling to you.

Comment: My limited experience with Minute Physics is that he oversimplifies the issue and winds up explaining it incorrectly (or at least explaining it in a way that can be easily misunderstood). If you really want to learn physics, open a textbook (e.g., Halliday, Walker & Resnick or similar), don't waste your time on internet videos.

Comment: Hi HyperLuminal: Well, politically speaking, I suspect your question might have been more warmly received if you had not stuck that "Bah" in the middle of it... :)  However, it's a good question. If Feynman spent an entire book (QED) to explain the most abstract and mathematically precise of all quantum theories, QED, in completely non-math terms, I would think that surely tunneling is also fair gain. You need math for precision, sure, but as in the QED case, the most fundamental principles of physics usually have a certain simplicity to them that enables non-math explanations.

Comment: The problem, really, is that you just asked and extremely _hard_ simple question. Tunneling is usually just explained in terms of the precisely defined tunneling probabilities, which certainly works, but is unsatisfying. Part of the problem is there is no good analogy to the quantum concept of a "very high but very thin energy barrier." It sounds too much like a high-lipped cup made of steel, and we know very well that marbles don't just "tunnel" through such constructs. So: The classical analogy, whatever it may be, is _not_ that. It's something a bit different. So again: Good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to look at quantum mechanics is through the dynamics.

One way to look at the dynamics is through the Schrödinger equation and there is nothing wrong with that. Since it is a linear equation it does encourage one to look at particular solutions and then make a general solution as a simple sum of those solutions, which can sometimes delay understanding how a particular system works. Another approach is to follow the probability current and then to see what makes that change.

When you look at the probability current, it is  not linear (for experts it is more bilinear) so is more directly posed in terms of the actual wave function of the actual system.

So let's look at tunneling from the point of view of a younger high schooler.

The current is proportional to the wave and how much it is changing (its gradient). The wave is like how much is there (the magnitude) and if it was real the gradient would measure how much stronger it is in one place than the other. However, it is complex, so the gradient can also measure how the phase changes. The change in phase from here to there is actually a stand in for how the density of the wave flows from one place to another. For experts, when $\Psi(x,y,z,t)$=$R(x,y,z,t)e^{iS(x,y,z,t)/\hbar}$ then the probability current is $\vec  J$=$\frac{R^2}{m}\vec\nabla S.$

So the change in phase from here to there is a direct analog of how the probability current is flowing. You can imagine that the wavefunction tells you all these different possibilities. And the fact that it is a complex field means it tells you about where these possibilities are and how they flow (this is common in physics to use a complex field to represent both what it is right now and how it is changing).

Now how does that current change? We know how it flows from here to there, like knowing the flow of water everywhere in a river. Just like with water we need to know how the phase (the velocity) changes in time. Based on where you are relative to everything else there is a classical force that naturally makes velocities change in exactly the way you expect, but in quantum mechanics there is a completely new force one based on whether there is a bigger density of possibilities on one side than the other. It is like a particle has to go up a hill where the hill has a height of $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\vec\nabla^2R}{R}$ i.e. the term $\vec\nabla^2R$ measures how the density of possibilities $R$ deviates from the average values around it. Thus where there are less possibilities than around it, there is an extra push into that region. This is similar to water if it wanted to rush into a region with less density except there is a very very strange property since you divide by $R$ as well you can get large pushes even when there is little density in the whole region. And this acts just like a potential so it is like storing energy in the shape of then possibilities. For instance if all the possibilities have the right density profile you can get a force that cancels the classical forces everywhere, no velocities change, and it is even possible to have zero velocity, so the analogy of energy is stored entirely in the shape profile of the wave of possibilities and in the classical potential.

So now let's get to tunneling properly. Tunneling happens when the classical forces by themselves are not strong enough to push you through a barrier, but if there is a higher density of possibilities on one side of the barrier this can provide an entirely new and quantum force that can push the wave into the classically forbidden region. You can see this in statics if you look at one those special profiles where nothing is moving, the shale everywhere is exactly enough to produce a force that counters the  classical forces. Or you can see it with dynamics.

In dynamics you can watch the leading edge of a packet slow down as it approaches a classical hill, it slows down relative to the wave behind it, but that leads to a higher density behind that leading edge which means the quantum force pushes it up the hill harder than it otherwise would go. If the hill is larger this repeats over and over again until there is such a strong build up behind that leading edge that the leading edge is finally pushed through the barrier.

That's tunneling. And since a lot of possibilities have to pile up behind that leading edge for a high and wide barrier only the tip of the leading edge makes it through. This is why tunneling it rare. Now, to be fair, because of that $1/R$ term it is a relative lot that piles behind it, not a lot. So you want a mismatch between the average that is proportionate to how much is there. So the effect is still that only the tip of the leading edge makes it through, but not much makes it through. That buildup pushed both ways, so as the leading edge got pushed through, the whole rest of the wave got pushed back.

And normally a potential pushes back, they just get pushed back stronger and earlier than they do classically. And the whole process depends on the original shape profile of the wave.

Even with no classical potential the wave can push itself apart because any region of higher than (local) average (relative to how much is there) exerts a force away from itself. This is entirely quantum.

When I say that, this is because classically if there was a possibility for a particle to be here or there then each possibility would dynamically evolve as if it were the only thing. In quantum mechanics these possibilities are real in the sense that they actually interfere with each other and force a flow of possibilities from the current and the current (velocity) changes not just from the classical potential but also from the quantum potential of $-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\vec\nabla^2R}{R}$ so that regions where the possibilities are denser than the regions around them exert forces to even them out and regions where the possibilities are less dense than the regions around them also exert forces to even them out. These forces can be overcome by the classical forces, thus regions can get more dense with possibilities until the quantum force is strong enough to balance the classical force pushing them there.

So there is an expectation for possibilities to roll down a classical hill. Its just that they can also go up a classical hill if they were flowing towards the hill and have a bigger density of possibilities driving them through it.

This whole story can be easily misunderstood. In particular you don't need to track how each bit of probability flows from here to there to get your final answer. So all of this intuition is not required to get the correct answer. And so (well) over 99% of Physicists do not learn this approach. And I don't want you to think it is required.

The alternative is to just not pay attention to where the probabilities is when you aren't looking at it, and to not bother even asking how it got from one place to another, just do some math that correctly tells you how many possibilities (the probability) are on the other side of the barrier.

There is nothing wrong with that. Two ways of getting the same answers are equally valid. But if you don't ask what goes on when you don't look then you can't answer it. But it is OK to not answer it because stories about what happen when you don't look (in between looking) are just that, stories. Not science.

And tracking the flow of probability and tracking what makes it change can be overkill if you also e tracking the whole wave over time.

But if they produce the same answers and you can learn how to use one to gain a better understanding, that can be useful. If one of them would be a bunch of symbols that don't mean anything to you then it might be less useful even if you get all the right answers.

That said, neither is simple.

Comment: Hello. I think this is a very interesting answer(I am one of those that have not heard until now an approach like this.All we have done up until in  university was to calculate the factors of transmission or reflection or the probabilities of where to find the "particle"). You wrote: Tunneling happens when the classical forces by themselves are not strong enough to push you through a barrier, but if there is a higher density of possibilities on one side of the barrier this can provide an entirely new and quantum force that can push the wave into the classically forbidden region." May I ask..

Comment: ...continue: Can this force expressed mathematically, and studied that way as we do with other forces? Are there propositions about it's nature? Thank you and forgive me for the long comment.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack The force comes from the potential $-(\hbar^2\nabla^2R)/(2mR)$. But to compute it you need to know $\nabla^2R.$ And there are two approaches to do that. Pilot wave theory first solves for the dynamics of the entire wave $\Psi$ according to the Schrödinger equation, then extracts $R(x,y,z,t)$ from that and then gets the quantum potential from that. The other approach, Many Interacting Worlds (**not** the same as Many Worlds Interpretation) tracks a large number of particles/worlds, each gets an approximation of the quantum potential based on the density of worlds around it.

Comment: Is this force considered to be a "real" cause for the quantum tunneling in orthodox qm or in this interpretation it's not needed? The only thing necessary is to calculate the proper possibilities or the probability current? Excuse if I'm forgetting some facts here. Thanks.

Comment: @ConstantineBlack The orthodoxy is to not ask, to shut and calculate. But the orthodoxy does use the current for computing transmission and reflection coefficients so the probability current is an essential aspect. But you can compute it without reference to the force or the potential from whence it came. But if you want to watch a wave penetrate a barrier you can track the current and investigate what makes the current change and express that in terms comparable to a potential. Almost no one does. Because you can already compute the current and so are already ready to shut up and calculate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If we take the wavefunction to exist only in configuration space, then, is this potential also only in configuration space, or would you suggest that it's something similar like the other mathematical functions(potentials) that describe fields or forces that exhibit real space? Or maybe, you would suggest that configuration space has some physical meaning other than just a mathematical tool? I am currently reading QM A modern development by Ballentine, and there the wavefunction, is stated, that isn't a real field or the particle. So if this potential acts on the...

Comment: ... probability current, how does it?

Comment: @ConstantineBlack In quantum mechanics a assical potential is also a function of configuration space for instance for the full hydrogen atom you have $V=ke^2/|\vec r_1-\vec r_2|$ you switch coordinates to center of mass coordinates and relative displacement, use a reduced mass and separate variables. And for a specific state the wave can penetrate outside the classical well because of the higher density closer to zero relative displacement.

Answer (score 2):

I like and upvoted the accepted answer, so my adding this (partial) answer is only to add a short and intentionally non-mathematical view to the answer. I find this a genuinely intriguing question that I think with some effort could be answered well in terms that are a lot less mysterious sounding. This answer is not that, but it is perhaps a start...

Imagine for a moment one of those pinball machines that drops a marble from a starting point at the top corner of an expanding triangle of pins that will bat it this way or that. At the bottom are a set of slots, let's say ten, into which the ball will fall. If the wall is designed well, the odds of the marble falling into any one slot will be equal.

The top of this triangle represents the past history of some particle, and the bottom of the triangle represents the expanded quantum representation of that particle over time. It spreads out over time, with the probability of the ball being "found" in any one of the ten slots. The chances of finding the ball in one of the ten slots is 0.1, or 10%.

Now here in a nutshell is the difference between classical physics and quantum physics. In classical physics, what you see happen in the pinball triangle is exactly what you get: Every ball finds its own very real, very definite path into its final slot. It's only when you look at the overall results that you see the pattern of an even 10% distribution over the ten slots.

In quantum mechanics, the *outcome* is exactly the same: The ball (it works better with a very small ball, such as a neutron) winds up in one of the ten slots, with each slot having a 0.1 chance of receiving a given neutron. So, nothing mysterious there!

What's new in quantum mechanics, or QM, is the introduction of a rather odd new factor: Until you *look* for the specific location of the particle in a specific slot, the particle behaves very much like a wave. That is by, by simply playing with the geometry of the pins in the triangle, you can make regions of the overall "wave" cancel out in odd ways that look a lot like, say, the way water waves in bowl form quiet areas and peaks.

This cancellation has nothing to do with direct blocking paths by pins, and in fact can work in just the opposite fashion. That is, some spots that *should* be more likely to receive the ball in a classical pinball setup become locations where the ball will *never* be found. Whenever that happens the changes of finding the ball in other slots always increases, so that the *total* probability of finding the ball somewhere always remains 1 (or 100%).

OK, so fine: QM sometime has particles behaving like waves. That's not exactly news. So what has any of this got to do with quantum tunneling?

Just this: In *both* the classical and QM cases, the ball cannot end up in slot unless there exists some viable path through time (from the top of the triangle of pins) and space (across each layer of the triangle of pins) by which it can wind up in a slot. While that path may get a little weird in the QM case where wave patterns are involved, it still has to be there.

In classical physics, that path is exactly what you see as the balls fall into the slots, recorded over time.

In QM, that path becomes a somewhat more abstract concept called a "probability current," but even that phrase boils down to saying that "there had to be a real chance for the ball to travel along that path to reach that final destination." If no such path exists -- that is, if at some point there is no possibility along any path for the ball to wind up in a particular slot -- then it simply will never be found there. That is true for *both* the classical case and the QM case.

That is important, because it says this about the quantum effect called tunneling: It says that tunneling *cannot happen* unless you can construct a sort of "back history" by which the ball (or particle, or electron) could have plausibly wound up in that location.

Think about that for a moment...

It means in particular this: Tunneling is not magic. That is, whether the situation is quantum mechanical or not, if you truly have a case where there is *no* path by which a particle could wind up inside a closed sphere or region of space, then the particle will never be found there... period. QM cannot overcome zero probability, even in tunneling.

But wait a minute! What about all that tunneling stuff they invoke in cases such as hydrogen fusion, where a proton is more likely to bind with heavy hydrogen because of quantum tunneling of the proton? Isn't that pretty much the same thing as having an impenetrable shell around the heavy hydrogen nucleus?

That's where the wave part comes in again, in a very important way.

Recall that in QM, the way the particle is guided depends on the wave, not on the location of the particle itself in a classical sense.

As anyone who plays music knows, it's actually very hard to get a completely pure wave, or what is called a sinusoidal wave -- that pure tone that comes off of a tuning fork, for example. Most waves are instead mixes of many frequencies. If you cut off sine waves, such as in an amplifier that maxes out, you also get an abundance of harsh-sounding high frequency sounds characteristic of some styles of electric guitar music.

In QM those higher frequencies also form for particles, in pretty much the same way. But in that case, there's a critical difference: A higher QM frequency also represents a more *energetic* form of the particle.

So strangely and rather paradoxically, the fact that a particle behaves like a wave in certain situations also enables it to behave is if it is more *energetic* than it really is. Energetic enough, in fact, to do things that classical mechanics would never allow for a particle of that energy level, such as a proton hitting a nucleus of heavy hydrogen to give hydrogen fusion.

So there is the real answer to "tunneling" over a very high energy barrier: Because it is represented as a wave, you can set up situations where *part of the wave* represents an energy level far higher than is possible classically.

Translate that into classical analogies, and here's the surprise: the particle does *not* truly tunnel the energy barrier after all. Instead, because its paths are guided by waves that when bumping up hard against a barrier (as with the maxed-out amplifier), some small part of its probability wave can gain enough energy to create a path that sloshes *over* that same energy barrier.

And that is what happens in devices such as tunneling diodes. The electron, acting as a wave, bumps up against a sharp barrier and produces harmonics far higher than those of the actual energy of the electron. When tuned well, those harmonics are strong enough to create a probability current *through* the barrier -- that is, a way for the electron to pass through the energy barrier, in real space, through real atoms. But its *impact* on those atoms is much less than it would be as a classical particle, since as a wave its impact is more subtle and much more diffuse.

But that does not mean that the electrons are not there! I say that for this reason: If you took a tunneling diode and instantly destroyed it with intense gamma rays that you somehow arranged to provide microscopic imaging of what is going on, guess what? Those higher frequency harmonics of the electron waves would be destroyed by the gamma rays, and you would actually *see* electrons caught right in the middle of the space they were supposedly unable to enter. No magic, no jumping through some weird non-space, just real electrons caught unawares in exactly the region where they were not supposed to be.

And with that... well, it's a more thorough explanation than I originally intended to give, but I think it also answers -- without using math -- what is going on *conceptually* with tunneling. The math just quantifies where and how those waves form, and thereby permits those broad concepts to be transformed into precise predictions and even carefully engineered devices.